# What is wrong with the binary_search predicate in my code

Tags: c++, stl

I was reading about the binary_search and then I tried to implement it using a predicate. Here is my code (I have also included the sort predicate I am using) . I am aware that less than is the default.This is the rough testing code

```
class person
{
public:
    int age;
};

//sort predicate
class less_than_key
{
public:
    inline bool operator()(const person& pa , const person& pb)
    {
        return (pa.age < pb.age);
    }
};

//Binary Search predicate
class bsearch_predicate
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const person& pa)
    {
        return pa.age == n;
    }
    bsearch_predicate(int i):n(i) {}
    int n;
};
```

Implementation

```
    person p;
p.age = 24;

std::vector<person> vec;
vec.push_back(p);

std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),less_than_key());

std::binary_search(vec.begin(),vec.end(),bsearch_predicate(24));
```

Now the binary_search here yields error however if I try that with the std::find_if as such

```
std::find_if(vec.begin(),vec.end(),bsearch_predicate(24));
```

The above works. I would appreciate if someonce could tell me why I am getting linker errors with std::binary_search from my code. The linker errors are:

```
Error   12  error C2676: binary '<' : 'const bsearch_predicate' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const bsearch_predicate'  d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   10  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate' d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'  d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'  d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate' d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   11  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'   d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   9   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'   d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate' d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const bsearch_predicate'   d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    2978    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `binary_search` function does not take an equality operator, but an *inequality* iterator that defines an order. You have to model the predicate as if it was a *less-than* comparison.

The reason  is that the `binary_search` algorithm *needs* to know about the relative order of the argument and the element it is looking at to decide what direction to continue the search. The element is considered found when neither `pred(*it,value)` nor `pred(value,*it)` is true (if neither value is smaller than the other, they are the same)

Comment: My predicate is already doing a less than comparison ? Am i missing something here?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: No, you are not: `bool bsearch_predicate::operator()(const person& pa){ return pa.age == n;}` Basically you need to use the same predicate to `binary_search` that you passed to `sort`.